# Return DateTime based on values in a pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working creating a data time column from a data that has "anual_quarters" as the column names and values for each data point of each quarter.

I was thinking of creating a custom function and using .apply to return a data I could use. But I can't seem to write a function the iterates over each row/col of the data using iterrows() and iteritems()

Heres the last thing I tried.

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_recent_orders(merged_data):
    for index, row in merged_data.iteritems():
        if row['q4_sales_2021'] > 0:
            return datetime(2021, 10, 1)
        elif row['q3_sales_2021'] > 0:
            return datetime(2021, 7, 1)
        elif row['q2_sales_2021'] > 0:
            return datetime(2021, 4, 1)
        elif row['q1_sales_2021'] > 0:
            return datetime(2021, 1, 1)
        elif row['q4_sales_2020'] > 0:
            return datetime(2020, 10, 1)
        elif row['q3_sales_2020'] > 0:
            return datetime(2020, 7, 1)
        elif row['q2_sales_2020'] > 0:
            return datetime(2020, 4, 1)
        elif row['q1_sales_2020'] > 0:
            return datetime(2020, 1, 1)
        else:
            return None
merged_data['last_order'] = merged_data.apply(get_recent_orders, axis=0)
```

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(merged_data.head())`. My first thought is to use `numpy.select`, it should be the perfect use case but maybe there is a simple way but it depends on your dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [merged_data['q4_sales_2021'].gt(0), 
              merged_data['q3_sales_2021'].gt(0),
              merged_data['q2_sales_2021'].gt(0),
              merged_data['q1_sales_2021'].gt(0),
              merged_data['q4_sales_2020'].gt(0), 
              merged_data['q3_sales_2020'].gt(0),
              merged_data['q2_sales_2020'].gt(0),
              merged_data['q1_sales_2020'].gt(0)]

choices = [datetime(2021, 10, 1),
           datetime(2021, 7, 1),
           datetime(2021, 4, 1),
           datetime(2021, 1, 1),
           datetime(2020, 10, 1),
           datetime(2020, 7, 1),
           datetime(2020, 4, 1),
           datetime(2020, 1, 1)]

merged_data["last_order"] = np.select(conditions, choices, None)
```

Comment: Assuming there are only the stated quarters in the function, this is definitely the most simple answer.  If there are years of data, this could become quite time consuming.

Comment: print(merged_data['last_order'].head(q))
returns:
 0   2021-10-01
thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

With `np.select`:

```
condlist = [df['q4_sales_2021'] > 0,
            df['q3_sales_2021'] > 0,
            df['q2_sales_2021'] > 0,
            df['q1_sales_2021'] > 0,
            df['q4_sales_2020'] > 0,
            df['q3_sales_2020'] > 0,
            df['q2_sales_2020'] > 0,
            df['q1_sales_2020'] > 0]

choicelist = [datetime(2021, 10, 1),
              datetime(2021, 7, 1),
              datetime(2021, 4, 1),
              datetime(2021, 1, 1),
              datetime(2020, 10, 1),
              datetime(2020, 7, 1),
              datetime(2020, 4, 1),
              datetime(2020, 1, 1)]

default = pd.NAT

merged_data['last_order'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"annual_quarters": ["q4_sales_2021", "q3_sales_2021", "q2_sales_2021", "q1_sales_2021",
                                            "q4_sales_2020", "q3_sales_2020", "q2_sales_2020", "q1_sales_2020"]})

import datetime as dt

def get_recent_orders(quarter):
    month_list = [1, 4, 7, 10]
    month = month_list[int(str(quarter)[1])-1]
    year = int(str(quarter)[-4:])
    
    return dt.date(year, month, 1)

df["last_order"] = df["annual_quarters"].apply(get_recent_orders)
```

As the month will be Jan, Apr, Jul or Oct depending on Q1, 2, 3 or 4, you can return a `datetime.date` by finding the month value from the second string character, the year from the last 4 characters, and day = 1.  This way, no need to iterate over rows at all.